# How to use windows authentication to connect to MS SQL server from windows workstation in another domain with Python

Tags: python, sql-server, odbc, pyodbc, freetds

I'm trying to connect to `SQL server 2000` installed on `Windows server 2003` from `Windows Server 2008 R2` using `Python 3.4` and `pyodbc` module. Those servers are in different AD domains. `Windows only` authentication is enabled on SQL server and I can't change that.

```
drv = '{SQL server}'
svr = 'sql.my-domain.local'
usr = 'my-domain.local\testuser'
pwd = 'password'
db = 'testdb'
pyodbc.connect(driver=drv, server=svr, user=usr, password=pwd, database=db)
```

The connection above fails with the following error:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQLServer] 
Login failed for user 'svx-iroot.local\\sqlexecutive'. 
Reason: Not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection. (18452) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

There are some questions, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16515420/connecting-to-ms-sql-server-with-windows-authentication-using-python), suggesting to add `trusted_connection='yes'` argument to `pyodbc` connection for support of windows authentication but in this case it does not help because with this option local credentials are used and I need to provide credentials explicitly because originating workstation is in a different AD domain.

Creation of `User DSN` in `ODBC Data Source Administrator` with `SQL Server` driver fails with the same error mentioned above.

Is there a way to make this work?

Meanwhile I installed `FreeTDS`driver for Windows from http://sourceforge.net/projects/freetdswindows/ and connection test using `tsql` utility does work:

```
tsql -S sql.my-domain.local -U my-domain.local\testuser -P password
```

But `FreeTDS`driver is not available in `ODBC Data Source Administrator`. `FreeTDS` driver is traditionally used with `unixODBC`. Is it possible to use this driver in Windows environment with `pyodbc`?

Update:

It turns out `FreeTDS` binaries mentioned above include `unixODBC` as well. Configuration of `freetds.conf`, `odbc.ini` and `odbcinst.ini` was made like described, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16925825/having-troubles-with-unixodbc-freetds-and-pyodbc). But at this point I don't have understanding how `pyodbc` is supposed to know that `FreeTDS` driver exists. And indeed connection attempt with `FreeTDS` driver fails with the following error:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] 
Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

`Pyodbc` only knows about drivers available in `ODBC Data Source Administrator`:

[image: ODBC Data Source Administrator screenshot]

There are 2 ways to move forward. First option is to make `ODBC Data Source Administrator` aware of `FreeTDS` driver. To achieve that a new value needs to be created in registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers` with name `FreeTDS` and value `Installed`. Then a new key `FreeTDS` is created in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI` and settings for `FreeTDS` driver are set as string values in this registry key.

[image: FreeTDS registry settings]

After completion of this procedure `FreeTDS` driver became available in `ODBC Data Source Administrator` but connection still failed. Attempt to create `User DSN` in `ODBC Data Source Administrator` with `FreeTDS` fails with error code `193` which is caused by incompatibility of 64 bit `ODBC Data Source Administrator` and 32 bit version `FreeTDS`. I don't have 64 bit version of `FreeTDS` available. Potentially it could be possible to compile it from source.

Another option is to make `pyodbc` use another driver manager (`unixODBC`) instead of `ODBC Data Source Administrator`. Don't know how to approach that yet.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using [pymssql](https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql) version 2.1.3 installed with a wheel obtained from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pymssql. It has `FreeTDS` included and it worked right out of the box:

```
import pymssql
conn = pymssql.connect(
  host=r'sql.my-domain.local',
  user=r'my-domain.local\testuser',
  password='password',
  database='testdb'
)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM testtable')
```